# Parallel Port Emulator

Tags: hardware, parallel-port

It seem that my USB -> parallel port converter(SUNIX ComHUB) don't show as parallel port in Windows Hardware. But instead as "Support for USB printer port". Is there anyway for me for me to make Windows recognise it as parallel port in Windows?

If not.
Are there any parallel port emulator that I can test my program too?

Thank you

EDIT: Im using 64bit driver from [logix4u](http://logix4u.net/Legacy_Ports/Parallel_Port/Inpoutx64.dll_for_WIN_XP_64_bit.html). And C# as programming lang.

Comment: Retagged as there's no relevance to C# here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some [virtual port offerings](http://www.smartcode.com/downloads/virtual-parallel-port-usb-port.html) that might fit your needs.